# PHP ODBC - Access 2007: Function Call Problems: odbc_columns

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I have mananed to use the odbc_connect like the following for access 2007 and 2003 and I can get data. But when I try to get the column names the following function will not work for access 2007 but will for acccess 2003 - why?

```
if($type[1]=='mdb'){

    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);

}else{

    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);
}

function get_columns($activity_file){

    global $connection;

    global $typee;

    $coulmn_array = array();

    $result = odbc_columns($connection, $typee, "", $activity_file, "%");

    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {

        $coulmn_array[] = odbc_result($result, "COLUMN_NAME");

    }

    echo '<br>Exporting table '.$activity_file;

    return $coulmn_array;

}
```

I mean I can get the data and everything, it just seems this function just won't work!

Please help!

### Update

I had a google around and found [this thread](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10223481.html).

I can confirm what this person is saying. Supplying a table_name means this won't work. But if you don't it will. This isn't acceptable as what columns are being returned and for what table? I need to know this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but there was a problem with the ODBC function SQLDescribeCol and SQLColAttributes related to Access 2007.  Those functions would likely be used by `odbc_columns`.  It is described in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941877).

Comment: I hope this isn't what is effecting me! I had a look at my office 2007 install and it shows this version number: 12.0.6425.1000.But the version for the patch looks like its: 12.0.6300.5000 - meaning I have hopefully have surpassed this version and therefore have a fix for it.

Comment: @Abs: That probably is not it then.  Just as a sanity check, you might look at the version of aceodbc.dll to make sure it matches, but it sounds like you have the correct versions.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that though. Something to be aware when I distribute these scripts.